# How to implement ASP.NET Core 1.0 GridControl with dynamic input functionality

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We would like to implement a web application where we need datagrids for showing and manipulating data. I am new to web development and as we are mainly developing in *C#* in our company at the moment and as we are starting from scratch we are considering the new *ASP.NET Core* framework.

I made some tutorials so far e.g. [ASP.NET](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started.html) and now try to figure out how one would implement a datagrid with dynamic input functinality like the one from [EXT.NET](http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Editable/Editor_with_DirectMethod/).

**Main question:** Are there any libraries for *ASP.NET Core 1.0* already with similar behaviour to [EXT.NET](http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Editable/Editor_with_DirectMethod/)'s datagrid or will we have to do an own implementation? Any suggestions for ready to use components either open source or commercial are highly appreciated.

<strike>Would it make sense if possible to use [EXT.NET](http://examples1.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Editable/Editor_with_DirectMethod/) components in combination with *ASP.NET Core* or is it a bad idea?</strike>

Comment: Bad question as it tends to get opinion based answers which isn't suitable for SO. I person wouldn't use it, from a quick look the zip package only has MVC4 and MVC5 libraries, which mean you won't even be able to use it with ASP.NET Core's MVC stack, as doesn't have any dependencies on System.Web anymore (which old ASP.NET stack did), because System.Web tied it tightly to IIS and Windows. Second point, it's pretty blown up package for a  simple requirement.

Comment: You'd be better to go with ASP.NET Core "WebApi"  and a lightweight JS framework (vue.js maybe, if you don't want big SPA apps like angular.js has to offer). ExtJS (which Ext.net is based on) is a huge full-blown monster with huge java script files if you include all features and is pretty slow in execution inside the browser, especially on websites accessible from the internet

Comment: Our main usage will be in a local network but as well accessible from the internet. The second question about EXT.NET was more thought as an example about how we would like a grid component to work - so maybe the emphasis was too strong on that one. I will edit the question to make it more clear.